Identify a Vintage Colored Indian Movie
I am trying to identify an Indian that I have watched back in 2001. It was old. 
I remember there was this funny scene. There was this actor in the movie and he was standing in front of a house while eyeing an attractive girl and then the old woman (inside that house) looks at him and gets jealous thinking he is her husband. 
So, she drags him inside the house where she seduces him and then he tries to escape telling her that only devils have intimate relations in the morning. 
Then, when she tries to make her move, her actual husband calls on her from outside the house. Then the camera shows that the guy outside is the exactly like the actor inside. The old woman gets confused and the actor inside rushes out the window.
I believe the movie is in Eastman colors (thanks @Panther). The actor had a dark colored skin and he was a bit overweight but not fat. He had a funny voice. I think his face was a bit saggy but I am not sure.
If I remember right there were two main actors in this movie. This guy and another guy who was thin. The thin actor was the main hero and the overweight guy was his sidekick. I wish I could remember more but that is all could remember.
Does anyone know the name of this movie?

You might want to use a more descriptive question title.

Old ? was it black  & White ?

Hi @Paulie_D, could you give me some tips on making the title clearer?

Try to think of the plot of the movie, even use a basic description of the scene you mention. Was the m ovie about mistaken identity or something else.

@Panther, I believe it was in colors but not the clear colors you see in recent movies. I do not know how to describe this, exactly. You know how you would watch an old video tape and you see there is a lot of noise in the colors.

Understood it was called as Eastman color or something similar.

@Paulie_D, I was young when I watched this movie. I remember that scene cause it was really hilarious. I think the actor was a bit overweight but not fat. He also had this hilarious voice that would make you laugh whenever he speaks.

@Panther, yes I googled Eastman colors and saw the images. They were something similar.

Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the actual question.

@Napoleon Wilson, will do.
